# Access the OrderedDict and TensorSpec separately from PrefetchDataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am still new to tensorflow and learning the basics. This is the scenario of load data from CSV file.

```
def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size,
      column_names= column_names,
      label_name = label_names,
      na_value = '?',
      num_epochs = 1,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset
```

This returns a *PrefetchDataset*.

```
raw_train_data = get_dataset(train_file_path)
type(raw_train_data)
```

```
tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset
```

Looking into the element_spec, of this dataset, it shows a tuple like structure, where the features are in a OrderedDict and the labels are a Tensor.

```
raw_train_data.element_spec
```

```
(OrderedDict([('sex', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('age', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)),
              ('n_siblings_spouses',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
              ('parch', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
              ('fare', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)),
              ('class', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('deck', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('embark_town',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('alone',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None))]),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

Is it possible to access the OrderedDict and the tensor separately? The goal is to perform data analysis (like in pandas) to find information like the unique values of each of the tensors (thereby, the unique values in a column/ feature of the dataset), the range of values, the statistics of the values (similar to pd.describe). Is it possible to perform such analysis using tensorflow?

I have noticed that with the help of a batch of the dataset, one can access the features and labels separately and look into some information of each of the comprising tensors.

```
temp_dataset = get_dataset(train_file_path, select_columns = selected_subset_columns)
features, label = next(iter(temp_dataset))

features
```

```
OrderedDict([('sex',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'female', b'male', b'male', b'female', b'female'], dtype=object)>),
             ('age',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([35., 30., 20., 27., 19.], dtype=float32)>),
             ('n_siblings_spouses',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>),
             ('class',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'Third', b'First', b'Third', b'Second', b'Third'], dtype=object)>),
             ('deck',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'unknown', b'C', b'unknown', b'E', b'unknown'], dtype=object)>),
             ('alone',
              <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'n', b'y', b'n', b'y', b'n'], dtype=object)>)])
```

```
features.keys()
```

```
odict_keys(['sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'class', 'deck', 'alone'])
```

```
tf.unique(features['sex']).y.numpy()
```

```
array([b'female', b'male'], dtype=object)
```

However, this information of a batch need not necessarily be similar to the rest of the dataset. Is there a easier way extract this information and perform the analysis? Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `raw_train_data.element_spec`variable is a `tuple` object.

So you can separate OrderedDict and TensorSpec by unpacking the tuple as follows:

````
a, b = raw_train_data.element_spec

print(a)
print()
print(b)

>>>

OrderedDict([('sex', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('age', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)),
              ('n_siblings_spouses',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
              ('parch', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)),
              ('fare', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)),
              ('class', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('deck', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('embark_town',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)),
              ('alone',
               TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None))]

 TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)```
````